# Call a templated member function with std::async

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible and how to call a templated member function of a class using std::async (preferably without using std::bind)? Please explain if C++11 or C++14 standard allows such a call in general and how to make it work in MSVS2013 in particular.

```
#include <future>

template<typename T> void non_member_template(T val) {}

struct X
{
    void member_non_template(int val) {}
    template<typename T> void member_template(T val) {}
    void call()
    {
        int val = 123;
        std::async(std::launch::async, &non_member_template<int>, val); // ok
        std::async(std::launch::async, &X::member_non_template, this, val); // ok
        std::async(std::launch::async, &X::member_template<int>, this, val); // error
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.call();
}
```

Comment: This should compile, I get no error with gcc or clang. Could be a bug in MSVC.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Different compilers give different error message and since templates are involved they are long and incomprehensible. I get an error from MSVS2013 and MSVS2015 (at rise4fun.com) and some version of GCC when selecting C++14 at ideone.com.

Comment: When building on VS2013, I get this error:  `MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1.`  and no other information.

Comment: The compiler that runs on Ideone doesn't support multithreading. The errors are undefined references - they have nothing to do with templates. You can see that it compiles [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NotIAVhKNxKzAKet). It could just be a bug in the thread library that ships with MSVC.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Reported as a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1090183 . Lets see what Microsoft says to this.

Comment: you could cast it in the meanwhile: `std::async(std::launch::async, (void(X::*)(int))&X::member_template<int>, this, val);`

Comment: Casting is like applying brute force. In this case, it's casting it even bruter force because you suggest a C-style cast. Using brute force when you don't understand something is... well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 and 2015 Preview which is going to be fixed in the future version of Visual C++: [Passing member template function to std::async produces compilation error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1090183/passing-member-template-function-to-std-async-produces-compilation-error).

So the example program is valid C++ code and if you need a workaround for Visual C++ 2013 use a cast in the last call to `std::async` as suggested in the comments:

```
static_cast<void(X::*)(int)>(&X::member_template<int>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen code break a compiler before, but here you go:

[image: error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1]

I'd suggest the same thing as Axalo in the comments above, you can solve the compile error by casting.

```
#include <future>

template<typename T> void non_member_template( T val ) {}

struct X
{
    void member_non_template( int val ) {}
    template<typename T> void member_template( T val ) {}
    void call()
    {
        int val = 123;
        std::async( std::launch::async,  &non_member_template<int>, val ); // ok
        std::async( std::launch::async, &X::member_non_template, this, val ); // ok
        //std::async( std::launch::async, &X::member_template<int>, this, val ); // error
        std::async( std::launch::async, static_cast< void ( X::* )( int )>( &X::member_template<int> ), this, val ); // ok
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.call();
}
```